# Using multiple imagepickers on one view

Tags: image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a working imagepicker that upon button click and hold gesture, allows the user to upload an image to the disk, and the user can change the image using the same gesture. The only issue is, however, I need this to be done twice on the same view (i.e. I have two imageviews, two buttons to change each of the imageviews, etc.), and I am stumped on how to get the second one to work. This is essentially what the view looks like:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
//
// Saving into Documents folder
//
NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/first.png"];

BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                  contents:nil attributes:nil];

if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
} else {
    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])];
    [myFileHandle closeFile];
}

//
// Loading from documents
//
NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
self.chosenImage = loadedImage;
[self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)onLongTile:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
switch ([gesture state]) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
        NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Photo Options"; //Action Sheet Title
        NSString *type = @"Upload Photo";
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel";
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:type, nil];
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];            }

}
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Photo"]) {
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Updated code with tags:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

if (self.imageViewOne.tag == 100)
{
    //
    // Saving into Documents folder
    //
    NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/one.png"];

    BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                      contents:nil attributes:nil];

    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
    } else {
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
        [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])];
        [myFileHandle closeFile];
    }

    //
    // Loading from documents
    //
    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
    self.chosenImageOne = loadedImage;
    [self.imageViewOne setImage:self.chosenImageOne];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
if (self.imageViewTwo.tag == 200)
{
    //
    // Saving into Documents folder
    //
    NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/two.png"];

    BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                      contents:nil attributes:nil];

    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
    } else {
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
        [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])];
        [myFileHandle closeFile];
    }

    //
    // Loading from documents
    //
    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
    self.chosenImageTwo = loadedImage;
    [self.imageViewTwo setImage:self.chosenImageTwo];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of the question, set tags to your `UIImageView` and change is accordingly. something like:

```
[self.imageViewOne setTag:100];
[self.imageViewTne setTag:200];
```

And then in your delegates you can check the tag value and do the needful:

```
if ( imageView.tag == 100)
{
    // Code for first imageView
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I am relatively new to objective-c. I set imageViewOne and imageViewTwo to the given tags, and tried to implement them in the imagePickerController method. When I tested it, it now uploads the same image to both spots whenever I click either button (i.e. the button to change imageViewOne and the button to change imageViewTwo). I added my updated code to my original post. Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what do you want to do? You have two imageViews right? So when you click on the top button, you want to load an image into the first imageView and when you click on the second button you want to load another image selected into the second imageView?

Comment: One way you can do that is to implemeted two UIImagePickerControllers. And like I said, set a tag for each of the pickers. And when the delegate gets called, handle them separately for each based on the tag. Check this link out for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328859/identifying-different-pickers-in-uiimagepickercontroller-delegate